# UWP : How to suppress a key press event in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I have a winform code to suppress a keypress. Here it is

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete) {
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

I want the same thing in UWP and tried this

```
if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Up || e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Down || e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Delete) {
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

But its giving me an error 'KeyRoutedEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'SuppressKeyPress' and no accessible extension method 'SuppressKeyPress' accepting a first argument of type 'KeyRoutedEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: `e.Handled = true`

Comment: The error is gone but its not suppressing the key. i'm still able to go up down and delete text

Comment: Make sure you subscribed to keydown event not keyup

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: Can I see the code where you add handler?

Comment: XAML: 

    <Grid Background="#241138" KeyDown="typeTest_KeyDown">
        <TextBox x:Name="typeTest" Grid.Row="1" AcceptsReturn="True" Margin="20" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="3" KeyDown="typeTest_KeyDown" IsSpellCheckEnabled="True"/>
    </Grid>

C#

    private void typeTest_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Up || e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Down || e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Delete)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

Answer (score 2):

You can block other handlers from processing that event by marking it as handled:

```
if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Up || e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Down || e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Delete)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

> **true** to mark the routed event handled; **false** to leave the routed event unhandled, which permits the event to potentially route further. The default is **false**.
>   -- [KeyRoutedEventArgs.Handled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.keyroutedeventargs.handled#Windows_UI_Xaml_Input_KeyRoutedEventArgs_Handled)

Comment: The error is gone but its not suppressing the key. i'm still able to go up down and delete text

Answer (score 2):

> UWP : How to suppress a key press event in UWP?

UWP does not contain  `SuppressKeyPress` within  `KeyRoutedEventArgs`, if you want to suppress a key press, you could detect `PreviewKeyDown` event for   `Window.Current.Content` that will be invoked before your `KeyDown` event. Please try the following code.

```
Window.Current.Content.PreviewKeyDown += Content_PreviewKeyDown;
private void Content_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Left | e.Key == VirtualKey.Right | e.Key == VirtualKey.Up | e.Key == VirtualKey.Down | e.KeyCode == VirtualKey.Delete)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = false;

    }
}
```